# What does System`Private`GetContentCode do?

Tags: undocumented, internals

I just came across this strange function.
It is next to `GetRefCount` and functions like `HasDownCodeQ`, so it may be something related to internal expression handling.
I tried to evaluate for various inputs and found that it gives constant, powers of 2-looking values. For example:

`` System`Private`GetContentCode[1] ``

> 536870912 ($2^{29}$)

`` System`Private`GetContentCode[Log] ``

> 16384 ($2^{14}$)

Any idea?

---

More info on it:

It seems to say something about the data type passed in:

Test this, for instance:

```
codedDataTypes =
  With[{e = #[[1]]},
       System`Private`GetContentCode[e] -> #[[2]]
       ] & /@
     Flatten[
      Map[#[[1]] -> (#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) &]@*
        Thread@*

        Replace[(l : Except[_List] -> v_) :> {l} -> v] /@
       {
        Range[0, 2] -> "Positive Machine Integer",
        Range[-2, -1] -> "Negative Machine Integer",
        RandomReal[] -> "Real Number",
        Take[Alphabet[], 3] -> "ASCII Character",
        Take[Alphabet["Cyrillic"], 3] -> "Non-ASCII Character",
        List@StringJoin[Take[Alphabet[], 5]] -> "String",
        List@StringJoin[Take[Alphabet["Cyrillic"], 5]] -> 
         "Foreign String",
        Thread[Range[3] -> Range[3]] -> "Integer Rule",
        Thread[Take[Alphabet[], 3] -> Take[Alphabet[], 3]] -> 
         "String Rule",
        Thread[Range[3] -> Take[Alphabet[], 3]] -> "Mixed Rule",
        <|1 -> 2|> -> "Association",
        <|1 -> 2, 2 -> 4|> -> "Association",
        sym[1, 2, 3] -> "Random Wrapper",
        sym[1, a] -> "Random Wrapper"
        }
      ] // GroupBy[First -> Last] // Map[Association];
codedDataTypes // Dataset
```

For compound data types (i.e. any expression that isn't a `Symbol`, `Numeric`, or `String`) it seems to be computed like this:

```
contentCodeTest[h_[v__]] :=

 DeleteDuplicates[Map[contentCodeTest, {h, v}]] // Total
contentCodeTest[h_] := System`Private`GetContentCode[h]
```

For numerics and strings there's only one value ever given:

```
System`Private`GetContentCode[10] // Log2

29
```

For pure symbols, there are many, but there are a small number of classes:

```
codedSymbols =
  Thread[
       # ->

        ToExpression[#, StandardForm, System`Private`GetContentCode]
       ] &@Names["System`*"] // GroupBy[Last -> First] // KeySort;

codedSymbols // Length

27

codedSymbols // Keys // Map[Log2]

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, \
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29}
```

Note that the 29 there is for the core data types and `List`:

```
KeySelect[codedSymbols, Log2[#] == 29 &]

<|536870912 -> {"Complex", "Integer", "List", "Rational", "Real", 
   "String"}|>
```

Note that this makes sense, in a way, with what was outlined before, as the `Head` of, say, `1` will be `Integer`. So you can sort-of consider `` System`Private`GetContentCode `` as working like `` System`Private`GetContentCode[Head[#]] ``. Not entirely though.

Note that `List` being there means that `` System`Private`GetContentCode[{1,2,3}]==System`Private`GetContentCode[1] ``

What this is telling us about internal layout or something, though, I don't know.

So a better question, really, is: what does `` System`Private`GetContentCode `` tell us--if anything--about how data-types are treated internally? (but note that this is probably as unanswerable as the original question)

Comment: This question should remain closed as it has not been edited, except for mark up.